# Recursive self-instantiation component [VHDL]

Tags: recursion, configuration, architecture, entity, vhdl

I'm starting a big project in VHDL and I would like to have every basic components (adders, multiplexers, registers, ...) written such that they are as most ordered as possible.

I'm thinking to use different architectures for each entity (to go through different layer of abstraction or different kind of implementation) and then select one using configurations.

My question is: is it possible to recursively self-instantiate a component but with a different configuration?

For example, let's take the adder:

```
entity ADDER is 
  generic( ... );
  port( ... );
end entity ADDER;
```

Then I would like to have different kind of architecture, for example:

```
-- Behavioral Add
architecture BHV of ADDER is
  out <= A + B;
end architecture BHV;


-- Ripple Carry Adder
architecture RCA of ADDER is 
  ...
end architecture RCA;


-- Carry Select Adder
architecture CSA of ADDER is
  component ADDER --   <== this should be configured as RCA
  ...
end architecture CSA;
```

Is it possible to configure the adder used inside the Carry Select with a Ripple Carry without ending in an infinite instantiation loop?

Comment: The answer to such a question is often just trying it out. I didn't know the answer until I had a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to configure the adder used inside the Carry Select with a Ripple Carry without ending in an infinite instantiation loop. With recursive instantiation a *termination condition* is required - something that terminates the recursion. The configuration is carrying out that role.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity ADDER is 
  generic( WIDTH : positive := 8 );
  port( CIN  : in  std_logic;
        A    : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        B    : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        F    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        COUT : out std_logic);
end entity ADDER;

-- Ripple Carry Adder
architecture RCA of ADDER is 
  signal CIN0 : unsigned(0 downto 0);
  signal FIN  : unsigned(WIDTH downto 0);
begin
  CIN0(0) <= CIN;
  FIN <= resize(unsigned(A), WIDTH+1) + resize(unsigned(B), WIDTH+1) + CIN0; -- yes, I know it's not a ripple carry adder
  F    <= std_logic_vector(FIN(WIDTH-1 downto 0));
  COUT <= FIN(WIDTH);
end architecture RCA;

-- Carry Select Adder
architecture CSA of ADDER is
  component ADDER is 
    generic( WIDTH : positive );
    port( CIN  : in  std_logic;
          A    : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
          B    : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
          F    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
          COUT : out std_logic);
  end component ADDER;
  signal F0, F1       : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
  signal COUT0, COUT1 : std_logic;
begin
  ADD0: ADDER generic map( WIDTH => WIDTH)
    port map ( 
          CIN  => '0'  ,
          A    => A    ,
          B    => B    ,
          F    => F0    ,
          COUT => COUT0 );
  ADD1: ADDER generic map( WIDTH => WIDTH)
    port map ( 
          CIN  => '1'  ,
          A    => A    ,
          B    => B    ,
          F    => F1    ,
          COUT => COUT1 );
  COUT <= COUT1 when CIN = '1' else COUT0;
  F    <= F1    when CIN = '1' else F0;
end architecture CSA;

-- here's the configuration
configuration CSAC of ADDER is
  for CSA
    for all: ADDER
      use entity work.ADDER(RCA);
    end for;
  end for;
end configuration CSAC;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Yu3